# Is wordpress plugin development active?

Tags: plugin-development

I've started working with wordpress and reading about plugins. Most of my searches and found plugins are from around 2008. Is there still active development or have developers moved on to a different CMS?

Comment: Yes, plugin development is active and a necessary addition to WordPress powered websites and webapps. And WordPress as a CMS, check this out: http://www.codeinwp.com/blog/mesmerizing-wordpress-stats/

Comment: I think you need to readjust your search terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is plenty of active development.

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=wordpress+latest+plugins&l=1

See the latest plugins page and notice the dates of the latest plugins... the first couple pages have plugins that were updated in the last few days.